# AJAX call before document.ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a requirment where in AJAX call has to happen before document.ready and the response from the AJAX call will be used to update some HTML elements.

So I have something like below:

```
var ajaxget = $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url:'/xxx/get',
      success: function(resp) {
       //logic
      }
});

$(document).ready(function(){
     $.when(ajaxget).done(function(resp) {
        //do ur logic
         $(documet).trigger("yyyy");
     });
});
//the above part is common across pages and placed in the <head>

//below one goes into multiple places based on the pages

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('yyyy', function() {
    });
});
```

The issue is the trigger event "yyyy" doesn't get executed in IE and intermittently on other browsers as well. Please help!

Comment: Why is is a "requirement" to do it before document.ready? Can't you just do it inside of document.ready, and make everything else wait for it? Not one of the down-voters by the way.

Comment: document.ready really takes a lot time, we need to make other ajax calls as well based on the first call. so the experience on the site is very clunky

Comment: Sorry that was just a typo,  this behavior is intermittent  $(document).on('yyyy', function() { //this doesn't get executed});

Answer (score 1):

Might be better to use `then()` instead of `success` to be sure that whatever happens in `success` is completed before the `$.when.done`

Note that `success` is not part of the promise chain

Try:

```
var ajaxget = $.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: '/xxx/get'
}).then(function(resp) {
  //logic
  return resp;
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  ajaxget.then(function(resp) {
    //do ur logic
    $(documet).trigger("yyyy");
  });
});
```

But also note you are triggering the event before you register it also if the order shown in question is correct

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me. Simply i defined "yyyy" event before triggering.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
                $(document).on("yyyy", function () {
                    console.log('triggered');
                });
                $.ajax({
                    type:'GET',
                    url:'some.jsp',//your url
                    success:function(resp){
                        //logic
                        $(document).trigger("yyyy");
                        console.log(resp);
                    }
                });
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Never ever use `async:false`. It is a terrible practice and is deprecated. You will see warnings in browser dev tools console

Comment: sorry, there is no point of using async false.I updated my code.

Comment: I realy can't put that above, as it could be page specific!

Comment: Where ever you may keep it make sure that your "yyyy" event loads before you trigger it.